# Installing Libboost 1.38 on Ubuntu 8.10

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu, ubuntu-8.10

Is there a way to Install Libboost 1.38 on Ubuntu 8.10? The highest version in my repositories is 1.35.  It has been suggested that there may be some repositories I could add to accomplish this, but my searches haven't yielded anything.

Do I have to resort to source code?  If so, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: +1 - I have the same sort of problem on Fedora, which apparently will only put the minor / bug releases into the repos :(

Comment: How can I see what Kim Grasman changed in my post?

Comment: Dan, you can click the age part of the "edited nn hours ago" to see the revision history. I re-tagged it, because I wanted to mark it as related to C++ and Boost, to get the attention of people who might know something about the problem. Hope that worked out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

- Upgrade to Jaunty (Ubuntu 9.04) which has 1.37. You can even incrementally upgrade to just its boost libraries (google for apt-pinning)
- use a more advanced method I often use: download the Debian package *sources* from Debian unstable (currently 1.38 with 1.39 in the NEW queue and available "real soon now") and rebuild those locally. You may want to google Debian package building -- and rest assured it is easy as the work has been done, you are merely building local variants from existing sources. This way you stay inside the package management system and are forward-compatible with upgrades
- if everything else fails, build from source.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, installing from source is straightforward. Get source, unpack, and run these commands:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local --libdir=/usr/local/lib
./bjam --layout=system install
```

Alternatively, you may wish to grab SVN HEAD, or wait for upcoming 1.40. Then, you can drop all of the above options except for `install`. You may want to review release notes at http://beta.boost.org to see if upcoming changes are "risky" for your case.

Answer (score 0):

`libboost1.37-dev` is in the Jaunty repository.

If you *must* have Boost 1.38, you'll have to compile it from sources yourself.